# "Proper" way to run shell script as a daemon

Tags: linux, shell-script, debian, daemon

I am writing a **shell script** that I would like to run as a daemon on startup *without using external tools like [daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) or [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/)*.

---

### Linux Daemon Writing HOWTO

According to the [Linux Daemon Writing HOWTO](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html), a *proper* daemon has the following characteristics:

- **forks** from the parent process
- **closes** all **file descriptors** (i.e., `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`)
- opens **logs** for writing (if configured)
- changes the **working directory** to one that is persistent (usually `/`)
- resets the **file mode mask** (umask)
- creates an unique **Session ID** (SID)

---

### *daemonize* Introduction

The [*daemonize* Introduction](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/#introduction) goes further, stating that a typical daemon also:

- disassociates from its **control terminal** (if there is one) and ignores all **terminal signals**
- disassociates from its **process group**
- handles `SIGCLD`

---

How would I do all this in a `sh`, `dash`, or `bash` script with common Linux tools only?

The script should be able to run on as many distros as possible without additional software, although *Debian* is our primary focus.

---

**NOTE:** I know there are plenty of answers on the *StackExchange* network recommending the use of `nohup` or `setsid`, but neither of these methods tackles all of the requirements above.

---

**EDIT:** The [daemon(7) manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/daemon.7.html) also gives some pointers, although there seem to be some differences between older-style `SysV` daemons and newer `systemd` ones. Since compatibility with a variety of distros is important, please ensure the answer makes clear any differences.

---

Comment: The "proper" way to craft your own shell script is to make it do its own logging, provide a method for launching it as a daemon, etc. Things like `daemon` and those other things are for running _arbitrary_ shell scripts with no provision for running as a daemon. Since you're the author, fully in control of how that script is written, make it so it can just be launched from a systemd unitfile or rc.d script. You _did_ specify "Proper"!

Answer (score 40):

Using [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/) you should be able to run a script as a daemon by creating a simple unit.
There are a lot of different [options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) you can add but this is about as simple as you can get.

Say you have a script `/usr/bin/mydaemon`.

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
  date;
  sleep 60;
done
```

Don't forget to `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/mydaemon`.

Create a unit `/etc/systemd/system/mydaemon.service`.

```
[Unit]
Description=My daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mydaemon
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To start the daemon run

```
systemctl start mydaemon.service
```

To start it at boot, enable it

```
systemctl enable mydaemon.service
```

*If* on a systemd based system, which a majority of Linux distributions are today, this isn't really an external tool. The negative is that it won't work everywhere.

Comment: While I like the systemd approach, the OP said "no external tools". There are Linux distributions which don't have systemd yet, or let you use choose between systemd and something else, e.g. OpenRC.

Comment: For distros that use systemd, `systemd` is no more of an "external tool" than `bash`.

Comment: Using that example unit didn't work for me (receiving a 203/EXEC failue). I added /bin/sh before the ExecStart path

Comment: @RobertoManfreda the script must be executable (see the `chmod` part of this answer)

Answer (score 13):

I am probably missing something here; why exactly wouldn't `nohup` be appropriate? Of course it's not enough *alone*, but supplementing it seems straightforward.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "DAEMON" ]; then
    # is this necessary? Add other signals at will (TTIN TTOU INT STOP TSTP)
    trap '' INT
    cd /tmp
    shift
    ### daemonized section ######
    for i in $( seq 1 10 ); do
        date
        sleep 5
    done
    #### end of daemonized section ####
    exit 0
fi

export PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
umask 022
# You can add nice and ionice before nohup but they might not be installed
nohup setsid $0 DAEMON $* 2>/var/log/mydaemon.err >/var/log/mydaemon.log &
```

As far as I can see:

- the output is appropriately redirected (use /dev/null if necessary)
- the umask is inherited
- `stdin` dies at the end of the parent script anyway
- the daemon.sh script is reparented to `init` (or `systemd`)

I have a strong feeling I'm missing the obvious. Downvote, but please tell me what it is :-)

Comment: I was about to suggest something very similar. I use `nohup` with `&` and I/O redirection to launch several non - `C` daemon utilities with perhaps the added security of wrapping your `nohup` command inside of a `su -c "nohup ... &" -s /bin/bash systemUser` to run the daemon as a non-privileged user.

Comment: when nohup met `ssh host -t 'nohup ./some_long_run_command&'` it will not work

Comment: @bzhu I'm sorry: how exactly did it "not work"? What happened, and what did you expect to happen? You may want to ask a new question and refer to this answer saying, "I tried this but...".

Comment: I mean the process some_long_run_commands on the server  can exit , after the ssh host -t './some_long_run_commands&' exit locally

Comment: @bzhu I'm not sure what the problem is...? I have tested this and what happens is that the local ssh exits, and the remote process **keeps running** until it terminates. You might want to intercept stderr on the launch and reap it via ssh, in case the remote script does not start (e.g. because its wd is not what you think, and ./command finds nothing).

Answer (score 4):

The Linux `screen` command contained in most distros can daemonize a shell script. I use it often. Here's a quick example to start, list, and quit a detached screen session...

```
# screen -dmS Session_Name  bash -c "while true; do date; sleep 60; done"

# screen -ls
There are screens on:
        8534.Session_Name       (04/04/2018 08:46:27 PM)        (Detached)

# screen -S Session_Name -X quit
```

Comment: `screen` doesn't deamonize shell script. It just run they in distinguished terminal and can detach from this terminal (like unplug keyboard from PC) without closing session. So, the program running in detached terminal is running in background. Therefore - detach pass program in background.